# Использование драггера для точек маршрута

Tags: яндекс-карты

как сделать такую реализацию. Есть маршрут, по клику на одну из точек маршрута, нужно, чтобы включился режим драггера и мы могли двигать карту, а точка оставалась бы на месте. Такое более точное позиционирование, как в приложении вызова такси, например.

В примерах не нашёл подобного решения. Там есть решение:
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/dragger
но, там нужен отдельный html элемент для драггера. А хотелось бы именно с точкой маршрута такое реализовать. Спасибо.

Comment: Почему не реализовать центровку экрана на точке, которую кликнули, и начать отслеживать изменение границ экрана, после завершения которого перестраивать маршрут уже через полученные координаты? Если такой вариант чем-то не подходит, покажите минимальный пример вашего кода на каком-нибудь https://jsbin.com и опишите сложности его модификации.

Comment: Я накидал пример, но у меня не получилось. Я не понимаю, как по клику на конкретную точку перестроить маршрут, чтобы роутер понял, в каком порядке меняется маршрут, чтобы не перепутались точки. А вдруг у меня их больше двух? Кроме того, баундчейдж срабатывает и при изменении зума карты, а надо же перестраивать маршрут только при перетаскивании.

https://jsbin.com/vayabofiwa/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Логика переопределения точек маршрута вроде описана в примере https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_view_options Чем вам не нравится boundschange непонятно — если центровать на точку при клике на ней, достаточно просто получать newCenter без усложнений: myMap.events.add('boundschange',function(e){console.log(e.get('newCenter'))}); Вам остаётся только настроить включение этого отслеживания после клика на кастомных ВИА-точках ваших, а после решить, как отключать этот режим и перестраивать маршрут.